# how to set request time out in Json Parser android

Tags: java, android, timeout, httpresponse

I have created the following function for getting  json from server as below :

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

when user in bad connection, it just loading without give any notification, my question is : how can i add such as toast when request time out or bad connection?

Comment: show your httprequest code..

Comment: @segi i only used this code for parse my json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, its been A long time, but I try to help, lets try to add this one :

```
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

and in your code, this will be :

```
 try {
         HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           
} catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
    Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", e.toString());
} catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){    
    Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", ste.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and to show message request time out, you can add such as alert message on your `onPostExecute()` if the result null or empty.

Comment: this is what I need to implement it in my code, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First of all set HttpRequestTimeOut like given below then add this logic into try and catch and add toast message into catch block when request timeout fails it'll show you toast message.

```
url = new URI(s.replace(" ", "%20"));

        Log.e("my webservice", "My webservice : " + url);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
```